# Headset Input Setting As Default

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I used to be able to use my Arctic P311 bluetooth headset for both, input and output, but now I can't. Well, it works fine as an output device but when I try to set it as a default input device in Sound Settings, settings windows breaks and goes down. At first it showed popups to report the problem but now it doesn't. It just dies now. I don't even know what is the problem.

How do I launch that application from terminal to see what it outputs? And/or maybe someone knows a potential problem?

P.S. Ubuntu 12.04 x64

**EDIT**

Thanks to the reply, I can now change input source but I now can't change output source. But it's because sound settings application crashes instantly as it shows up.

Comment: If you are suing pulseaudo, you can configure the default input device by `pavucontrol`.

Comment: See edit below on how to change the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Changing input source from command line

To see if an input source is defined, and to manually set a source as default for pulseaudio we may issue the following commands from a terminal:

```
pacmd list-sources # gives a list of all available sources
pacmd set-default-source <index or name> # changes the input default source
```

The `index` or `name` of the source is given in the first command. For a Bluetooth device connected through **Bluez** the source name will be:

```
bluez_source.xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx
```

Where `xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx` is the MAC of your headset (replace `:` by `_`).

#### Changing output sink from command line

Changing the output sink from command line can be done likewise by using the follwing commands

```
pacmd list-sinks #shows all sinks available
pacmd set-default-sink <index or name> # sets the output default sink
```

#### Autoconnect Bluetooth headset with pulseaudio

By editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` (as root) we can load the **[module-switch-on-connect](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules#module-switch-on-connect)** that enables the sound server to automatically switch to the headset when it becomes available. After making a backup (to be able to revert changes in case something breaks) insert the following line to your `default.pa`

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

To take effect we need to restart the pulseaudio server (run `pulseaudio -k`).

Comment: That worked but now Sound Settings can't open (crashes while loading) to change output source. It seems like current Sound Settings application has problems with bluetooth.

Comment: Yeah there are many issues/crashes reported with bluetooth and gnome-control-center. Hard to tell, which one applies to your issue.

Comment: For me, this temporarily broke Gnome-Shell, disabling my keyboard and ability to switch windows, but after a hard reboot my headset was properly auto-connected and selected as the output device.

Comment: Yeah, switch-on-connect  worked for me in 12.03. Thanks!